# DataTable not loading - Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined

Tags: jquery, ajax, datatables

Trying to load the the DataTable from an ajax request,

```
var url = '/my/url';
var table = $('#m_datatable').DataTable( {

            'ajax': {
              type: 'GET',
              'url': url,
              'data': function (d) {                
                return JSON.stringify( d );
              }
            }

        } );
```

HTML:

```
<table id="m_datatable" class="display" width="100%">
    <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Id</th>
                <th>Value1</th>
                <th>Value2</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
    </table>
```

Ajax request returns following json:

```
[
{
id: 1801,
value1: 1224589451,
value2: 1665229451
},
{
id: 1802,
value1: 1224589451,
value2: 1665229451
},
{
.
.
.
}
]
```

DataTable is showing empty and throwing following error in the console:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined http://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.12/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to tell the table what to do with the data, adding:

```
,
'columns': [{
  'data': 'id'
}, {
  'data': 'value1'
}, {
  'data': 'value2'
}]
```

...should do it, hope that helps. (Working example: https://jsfiddle.net/annoyingmouse/vvmcyacv/)